# What is the interpretation for $A^\bot$ in Linear logic?

Tags: linear-logic

I was reading the wikipedia page for linear logic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_logic

At some point it shows that a proposition may be raised to bottom as in $A^\bot$, what is the interpretation and the intuition behind this, and what is the relation to the non raised $A$?

Comment: Where exactly have you found it in the Wikipedia page?

Comment: It seems to be negation to me, anyway, it shows up on the syntax https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_logic#Syntax and also on the  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_logic#Sequent_calculus_presentation just after _Next we add initial sequents and cuts_